# What are the drawbacks of using a hash instead of a conditional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

One pattern I like to implement in order to make my code more declarative is to replace a long conditional like this:

```
def make_a_decision(value)
  if value == 1
    "One"
  elsif value == 2
    "Two"
  elsif value == 3
    "Three"
  end
end
```

With a hash like this:

```
def make_a_decision(value)
  { 1 => "One",
    2 => "Two",
    3 => "Three"
  }[value]
end
```

I like doing this because it replaces a conditional with an object that simply needs to respond to `[]`. It's also easier to read, in my opinion, partly due to the DRY nature of the hash.

I don't see any other Rubyists doing this, though. Why not?

Comment: I do something like that all the time. Except, I make the reference hash a frozen class constant (say, `FOO_MAPPING`) and just do `FOO_MAPPING[value]`.

Comment: Subjectively, I find it less readable. Objectively (unless Ruby optimizes it), you are redefining the hash object every time you call the function.

Comment: From what i've seen that pattern its very common, i use it a lot, but as a constant instead of a method.

Comment: i sometimes do this as well, but you can also use `case`

Comment: Note that, with a hash, you can mimic  the `else` clause in an `if...end` clause  by adding a default value ([Hash#default=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D)) or proc ([Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This approach uses more memory because it creates a new hash instance every time you call this method.
2. It is less readable than the original version for me.
3. Most likely this code will be changed and this change may involve some other condition than simple equality. Then, you will have to refactor the whole thing to implement the change.
4. Remember, DRY is not always a good thing. Think about reasons for your code to change before deduplication. DRY what is being highly duplicated already, but not prematurely.

Comment: For 1. extract the hash into frozen constant. For 2. learn a bit ruby. For 3. spaghetti is harder to refactor than a plain clean hash. 4. DRY is always a good thing. And 5. `case` should be used if not a hash (hash is still the best approach here.) `elsif` is so phpish.

Comment: Plain clear hash will not let you to introduce anything but equality. Also, hash instead of conditional is clearly not rubyish.  Here is a take on DRY: https://assortment.io/posts/reasons-against-the-dry-principle. Also, you will get quite a headache if you will have to change this structure in any way, introduce nested condtionals or add some other checks. This hash is just a way to transform values by the mapping, but it will fail if we will have to add up something but simple one-to-one transformation.